# How to securely git clone onto shared machine

Tags: git, github

Which method should I use to securely clone a GitHub repo onto a machine which other users have access to?

I am trying to prevent my credentials from being exposed during the cloning process. I have other private repos associated with my account which are not related to code I am trying to deploy.

For an example, if I use HTTPS then it's my understanding I run the risk of credentials being cached on the shared machine.

Other people can access the machine to use the code that I have deployed there.

If you were asked to deploy code that you have authored onto a friend's machine, how would you go about doing it while keeping your credentials safe?

Comment: Please can you click [edit] and add some more details about what you're asking. What do you mean by "safely" - what risks are you trying to protect against? And what do you mean by "shared" - what access do other people have to the computer?

Comment: Thanks, I have added some additional info.

Comment: What does this have to do with Git? Or GitHub? It seems to me you're asking what people who can access this machine can do. How do we know? You've told us nothing about how they access it and what they have access to when they do.

Comment: My question is specially about which method should be used to clone a gihub repo on a machine which will be shared by other users.
I know there is HTTPS and SSH, but my concern is that if I decide to use either of those then there is a possibility I could be giving more access than I realize. So how would you go about cloning a repo in that situation?

Comment: Are you logging into this computer via SSH or via the console or via some other mechanism?

Comment: I am logging onto the machine via remote desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard `git://` protocol over SSH, and use an SSH Key Agent to manage the identity files. This way, there is never a password or credential cache in play.

On your local machine: generate a private / public keypair, start the ssh-agent, give the agent the key, ssh to the shared host, then clone using the agent for its identity. The agent process and your identity can only be accessed through your active SSH session.

When you run a *git clone* from the shared host, it will use the key agent forward via the SSH connection. Using service like GitHub, GitLab, Gitea, etc., they all have the ability to associate public keys to your user account, providing you access to the git server.

```
# generate a new keypai
$ ssh-keygen
```

Upload `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to yhe git server in your account settings.

To clone,

From your local machine

```
# start agent, set environment variables with output
eval `ssh-keygen`

# give the agent the key
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# ssh to host, -A to forward agent
ssh -A user@1.2.3.4
```

The `-A` to the *ssh* command will forward the agent and identity manager to the remote host, now simply running a git clone, with the git/ssh protocol, will use the key files for authentication.

```
# clone it!
git clone git@github.com:owner/repo.git
```

Like many other things on a linux system however, a root user can [overcome boundaries](https://www.clockwork.com/news/2012/09/28/602/ssh_agent_hijacking/).

Answer (score 2):

Safest is you mount a thumb drive on a secure computer, clone to that using your credentials, then hand your friend the thumb drive.  You can copy and move factory-default clones freely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means an expert, but I assume these people log into the same user or at least have access to your local git repo.

I think cloning via **HTTPS** might be best for you. That way you can configure the cache to store the credentials only for a short time, e.g. 1 sec:

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=1'
```

(maybe with a `--global` flag if this is useful for more than one specific repo)

Fire more info on the credential helper cache:
[Read the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache)

Cloning via **SSH** is usually preferred if you don't want to have to enter any password. You just have to import your SSH key to GitHub (or whatever) but the key will be probably shared with the others as well, so they would have the ability to push without any authorization.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about your credentials being stored on your friend's computer, don't use those credentials.

Some suggestions:

- Set up a user on Github, grant it read only access to your project, and clone using that. You can even delete the user after you're finished if you want.
- Create an access token in Github, and use that to clone the repo. Again, you can give it read-only access, and delete it from your account when you're done.
- Add a new SSH key to your account, with a strong passphrase. You can copy that key to your friend's computer, but they can't use it without the passphrase. After you're finished, you can delete the key from your Github account.